# java GifSequenceWriter gif quality

Tags: java, animated-gif, image-quality

I have created JAVA app that uses **GifSequenceWriter** class for creating animated GIF from PNG sequence but I noticed that gif quality is pretty bad, so I would like to know if there is some option to set the maximum quality which is **256 colors** for the output gif as it seems that at the moment (by default) it uses **like 128 color only by default at best** (or even less!) which is very bad and almost unusable (shadows look terribly with all that color bending for example, no fine detail preserved etc.).

I tested creating **the same PNG sequence in separate GIF making tool** (a small Windows application) and the output gif is - compared to output from  GifSequenceWriter - **very very nice** (shadows are preserved with all the fine detail, almost invisible color bending etc.) so I guess there most probably should be some kind of IIOMetadataNode **.setAttribute()** value inside GifSequenceWriter class dealing with the image output quality but I was not able identify it myself...

Or maybe it should be some attribute from **imageWriteParam**? I searched a bit more and it seems that the actual "quality" parameter - at least for JPEG images - can be set via **imageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(float someFloatValueHere)** but when I try that it throw exceptions cos I guess there is no compression quality parameter for GIF...or is it?

Any guess anyone how to solve this issue?

BTW yes I have searched internet - no luck (I cannot even find any list of .setAttribute() options/values anywhere, strange, isn't it?)

---

**EDIT**
So after reading link with attribute values provided by @Marco13 I have implemented this code part into **GifSequenceWriter**:

```
IIOMetadataNode localColorTableNode = getNode(root, "LocalColorTable");
localColorTableNode.setAttribute("sizeOfLocalColorTable", "256");
localColorTableNode.setAttribute("sortFlag", "FALSE");

IIOMetadataNode colorTableEntryNode = getNode(localColorTableNode, "ColorTableEntry");
colorTableEntryNode.setAttribute("index", someIntA);
colorTableEntryNode.setAttribute("red", someIntB);
colorTableEntryNode.setAttribute("green", someIntC);
colorTableEntryNode.setAttribute("blue", someIntD);
```

But I have no clue what kind of **someIntA/someIntB/someIntC/someIntD** int values should I add - any guess anyone, am I going the right direction or what? I kind of feel I may be on the right spot (just maybe!) but I think I need a small kick or something...maybe I do not understand something right here and I need some explanation...or just pure right away solution for those int values...? :)

Comment: The option values are at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/gif_metadata.html . Beyond that, it's hard to give advice without example data.

Comment: @Marco13 thanx a lot for the link, gonna look at it...